# Error File does not exist at path. But File exists

Tags: php, laravel

[image: If you add dd]

[image: Code]

If you take away dd

```
[2023-10-30 15:20:19] local.ERROR: File does not exist at path C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\store\coolorca.cc\Modules/Addons/module.json. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Filesystem\\FileNotFoundException(code: 0): File does not exist at path C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\store\\coolorca.cc\\Modules/Addons/module.json. at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:60)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Json.php(112): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->get('C:\\\\Users\\\\Admin\\\\...')
#1 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Json.php(122): Nwidart\\Modules\\Json->getContents()
#2 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Json.php(41): Nwidart\\Modules\\Json->getAttributes()
#3 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Module.php(229): Nwidart\\Modules\\Json->__construct('C:\\\\Users\\\\Admin\\\\...', Object(Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem))
#4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php(188): Nwidart\\Modules\\Module->Nwidart\\Modules\\{closure}()
#5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php(330): value(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Module.php(230): Illuminate\\Support\\Arr::get(Array, 'module.json', Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Module.php(243): Nwidart\\Modules\\Module->json()
#8 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/FileRepository.php(293): Nwidart\\Modules\\Module->get('priority')
#9 [internal function]: Nwidart\\Modules\\FileRepository->Nwidart\\Modules\\{closure}(Object(Nwidart\\Modules\\Laravel\\Module), Object(Nwidart\\Modules\\Laravel\\Module))
#10 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/FileRepository.php(302): uasort(Array, Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/FileRepository.php(320): Nwidart\\Modules\\FileRepository->getOrdered()
#12 /var/www/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Providers/BootstrapServiceProvider.php(23): Nwidart\\Modules\\FileRepository->register()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.